# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: lines.split is not a function //i am just trying to read the lines of my txt file and I cant

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    let lines=[];
    let Array;
    fetch("questions.txt").then(response =>{
        console.log(response.status);
        response.text().then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
           Array=lines.split("\n");
        })
    });
</script>
```

i am just trying to read the lines of my txt file and I cant

Comment: Should be `response.split("\m")`

Comment: Also, you named a variable `Array`. This will hide the base-class `Array`, which you'll now only be able to access via `globalThis`.

Answer (score 2):

`lines` is already an array. Arrays cannot be split, as they already contain multiple elements.

This is probably what you meant to do:

```
let lines;
fetch("questions.txt").then(response =>{
    console.log(response.status);
    response.text().then(response =>{
        console.log(response);
        lines=response.split(/\r?\n/);
    })
});
```

Source (for splitting into lines): https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-of-code/blob/master/snippets/splitLines.md